# sql: join two tables and display records even if they are in first table and not in the second table

Tags: sql

I don't know if the title justifies the question but
i have 2 tables `table A a` and `table B b`. I am inner joining these two tables with

```
on (a.msisdn = b.frmsisdn or a.msisdn = b.tomsisdn)
```

in `table A` i have all the details of the users like `names, msisdn, regdate, status, address etc`

in `table B` i have user's transaction reports like `timestamp, frmsisdn, tomsisdn, reference, amounts etc`

Both tables have `MSISDN` as common but in `Table A` it is named as `MSISDN` and in `Table B` this can either be in `FRMSISDN` or `TOMSISDN` or will not be in any of the fields(usually users with no transactions).

But when i try to do like this, the report i am getting is not displaying the users who are in `Table A` with no entries in `Table B`, basically registered in the database but did not do any transactions as all.

Can someone tell me how do i include the `MSISDN` from `Table A` in the report even if they dont have an entry in `Table B`

Here is the query i am trying

```
select mai.msisdn, mai.firstname, mai.lastname, type as account_type,
alias as nickname, mai.regdate, mai.status,
amount as balance, count(trai.referenceid) as number_of_transactions,
sum(trai.amount) as sum_of_transactions from tableA mai
inner join tableC stk
on mai.msisdn = stk.msisdn
inner join tableB trai
on (mai.msisdn = trai.tomsisdn or mai.msisdn = trai.frmsisdn)
where trai.status = 0
and stk.walletid = 0
group by mai.msisdn, mai.firstname, mai.lastname, mai.type,
mai.alias, mai.regdate, mai.status,
stk.amount;
```

Comment: Hint : LEFT JOIN

Comment: show you sql code .. please

Comment: use left join or right join -- you know... the part of the query you didn't show us?  **that has to change**

Comment: On which RDBMS?

Comment: @serg, could be a right join... there is no way to know.

Comment: @scaisEdge added the query

Comment: @Serg tried left join but i am getting the same amount of records with both inner and left joins

Comment: Are you trying to do an outer join?

Answer (score 0):

If you need all the entry of table A also when there si no enty in table B the use LEFT join for table B

```
  select 
      mai.msisdn
    , mai.firstname
    , mai.lastname
    , type as account_type
    , alias as nickname
    , mai.regdate
    , mai.status
    , amount as balance
    , count(trai.referenceid) as number_of_transactions
    , sum(trai.amount) as sum_of_transactions 
  from tableA mai
  left join tableB trai on (mai.msisdn = trai.tomsisdn or mai.msisdn = trai.frmsisdn)
  inner join tableC stk on mai.msisdn = stk.msisdn
  where trai.status = 0
  and stk.walletid = 0
  group by 
      mai.msisdn
    , mai.firstname
    , mai.lastname
    , mai.type
    , mai.alias
    , mai.regdate
    , mai.status
    , stk.amount;
```

or if you problem is limited but the inner join for table C

try using inner join for this table too

```
  select 
      mai.msisdn
    , mai.firstname
    , mai.lastname
    , type as account_type
    , alias as nickname
    , mai.regdate
    , mai.status
    , amount as balance
    , count(trai.referenceid) as number_of_transactions
    , sum(trai.amount) as sum_of_transactions 
  from tableA mai
  left join tableB trai on (mai.msisdn = trai.tomsisdn or mai.msisdn = trai.frmsisdn)
  left join tableC stk on mai.msisdn = stk.msisdn
  where trai.status = 0
  and stk.walletid = 0
  group by 
      mai.msisdn
    , mai.firstname
    , mai.lastname
    , mai.type
    , mai.alias
    , mai.regdate
    , mai.status
    , stk.amount;
```

Comment: left join query is displaying the same number of results as inner join query did. Also all the records in Table A are in Table C

Comment: If the left join from table a and table b obtain the same number of row fo inner join this mean that all the rows match  ..  then could be that the constrain is due to table c .. i have update the answer

Comment: both queries in the answer give same number of results as the output. I have 128 records in Table A but in the output i am getting 111 records. 17 msisdn are not in Table B

Comment: You are using group by could be the 111 records are the disticnt mai.msisdn
    , mai.firstname
    , mai.lastname
    , mai.type
    , mai.alias
    , mai.regdate
    , mai.status
    , stk.amount; result

Comment: select distinct(msisdn) from tableC
where msisdn in (select distinct(msisdn) from tableA); this gives 128 results. i think all the data in TableA and TableC is distinct. in tableB there might be the same msisdn in two transactions.

Comment: Are your sure that the where condition don't interfere with your expected . result  .. left joit for A = 128 row return always 128  rows at least ..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134701/discussion-between-sai-avinash-and-scaisedge).

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
select mai.msisdn, mai.firstname, mai.lastname, type as account_type,
    alias as nickname, mai.regdate, mai.status,
    amount as balance, count(trai.referenceid) as number_of_transactions,
    sum(trai.amount) as sum_of_transactions 
from tableA mai
inner join tableC stk
   on mai.msisdn = stk.msisdn 
      and stk.walletid = 0
left join tableB trai
   on (mai.msisdn = trai.tomsisdn or mai.msisdn = trai.frmsisdn)
      and trai.status = 0     
group by mai.msisdn, mai.firstname, mai.lastname, mai.type,
mai.alias, mai.regdate, mai.status,
stk.amount;
```

See the difference how (at what stage) predicate is applied in LEFT JOIN .. ON and in WHERE.

Comment: i am getting the same records @Serg for both left joins or left join on table B

Comment: It means you have no unmatched row groups in mai which would be returned by left join contrary to inner join.